# 404 error out of no where on .php file

Tags: php, 404

I have a website which I've built that I have gone to a bunch of times today. Out of nowhere I receive a `404 Page Not Found` error, I didn't do anything.

The site loads an `index.html` file which points to a `main.php` file which loads the content. Those 2 files are in the same directory and intact. I have no idea why this is happening - how can I troubleshoot the problem?

I have already: cleared the cache, tried a new browser, triple-checked the file paths, and checked my hosts file.

Comment: Look at the logs on the server?

Comment: You didn't mention which webserver this is.  You should check the webserver's error log to see if it gives you clues about what file it was looking for.

Comment: ...it sounds like you tried everything ***except looking on the server to find out where the file went*** :-)

Comment: I did, it is there, it's hosted on IPower and they lied to me. The support tech said she could get to it, then I just asked someone to get to it from a computer they where in front of and it failed again. That's it, I'm calling them again.

Comment: This question is too localized and the person asking the question has not been clear on what the issue is and looks to be working with their hosting company currently to figure it out.  @Nathan, if you are still having issues once you talk to your hosting company, please come back and ask a new question with more detail and our community will be glad to help.